# Java can't get a continuous reading/writing to a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm studying electronic engineering but for my internship I've been asked to make a program that must communicate via a socket to a certain ip and port. The program has a main class which is the GUI and I made another class for the connection which runs parallel using a Thread. The problem is that when I click the "Connect" button that I have on my GUI, it only receives or sends once the data, despite having a while loop. To further receive and send data I must spam-click my connect and disconnect button.

```
public class ConnectionSocket implements Runnable {

    private final int port;
    private final String ipAddr;
    private final Observer observador;
    
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private Socket sc = null;
    
    private boolean inputAvailable = false;
    public boolean lastInput = false;
    private String nextOutputMessage;
    private boolean disconnect=false;
    private Observable observable;
    
    
    public ConnectionSocket(String ip, int p , Observer panel) {
        this.ipAddr = ip;
        this.port = p;
        this.observador = panel;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
 
        this.observable = new Observable();
        observable.addPropertyChangeListener(observador);
        this.observable.notifyData("Message Connected");
        System.out.print("\n**********************\nConectado\n**********************\n");
        
        while (!disconnect) {
            
            try {
                try {
                    sc = new Socket(this.ipAddr , this.port);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Socket TimeOut");
                }
                if(sc != null) {
                    out = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
                    in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
                }
                
                
                while(!disconnect){
                
                    if (sc != null) {

                        try {
                            if(in.available() != 0) {
                                receiveData();
                            }
                            else {
                                inputAvailable = false;
                            }
                        }
                        catch(IOException ex) {
                            System.out.println("***Read or write error***");
                            System.out.println(ex.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if ( sc != null ) {
                try { sc.close(); }
                catch ( IOException e ) {} 
            }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConnectionSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        //Close the socket
        cutConnection();
        System.out.print("\n**********************\nDesconectado\n**********************\n");
 
    }
    
    public void sendNewData(String msg) throws IOException {   //this method receives data from the GUI//
        nextOutputMessage = msg;
        sendData();
    }
    
    
    private synchronized void sendData() throws IOException { 
        
        System.out.println("Panel: " + nextOutputMessage);
        out.writeByte((byte) Integer.parseInt(nextOutputMessage));
    }
    
    private synchronized void receiveData() throws IOException {
        
        if(!inputAvailable)System.out.print("CUBE: ");
        inputAvailable = true;
        while(in.available() != 0) {
            byte dat = (byte) in.read();
            this.observable.notifyData(Character.toString((char) dat));
            System.out.print((char) dat);
        }
    }

    public void cutConnection() {
        try {
            disconnect = true;
            if(this.in != null) {
                this.in.close();
            }
            if(this.out != null) {
                this.out.close();
            }
            if(this.sc != null) {
                this.sc.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            this.sc = null;
        }
    }

}
```

I use two additional classes which use PropertyChangeListener to send the data received to the GUI, otherwise it just blocks it.
I receive and send data as ASCII code.

This is the method in the GUI class which starts the thread (the connection)

```
private void connect(String ip, int port) {

        jButton_connect.setText("Desconectar");
        labelMessage("Conectando...");
        observerPanel = new Observer(this);
        connection = new ConnectionSocket(ip , port, observerPanel);
        Thread t = new Thread(connection);
        t.start();
}
```

So basically I would appreciate any hint about what I'm doing wrong, because I can't really find any solution suitable for my needs. BTW any solution that includes getting rid of the double while loop would be great, as it consumes a lot of cpu in that point. Feel free to criticise any stupid thing I made because I had to learn java from zero to do this so it's probably not really good.
Thanks in advance

Edit 1: Does the `sc = new Socket(this.ipAddr , this.port);` sentence need to be called in the loop or once it's called it permanently bounds to that ip and port? I only need to connect to a specific ip and port. Thanks

Comment: A hint: reading and writing to a socket is a blocking operation. Normally you do not check for availability before reading, as it's just not needed, the thread will resume as soon as some piece of data is available. Looping that way is the cause of the CPU stress.

Comment: @LppEdd So if I just remove the condition of availability and put my "receiveData()" on the while loop it would sleep until some data is available? I tried that and debugged it, but it is continuously looping.

Comment: Why do you open the socket in the loop? Just open it outside of the loop and close it after the loop ends using a try-with-finally.